# Spring web service Servlet.init() for servlet spring-ws threw exception

Tags: spring, service, web

I am trying to learn Spring web services, I found this tutorial :
http://jeromebulanadi.wordpress.com/2010/02/25/basic-spring-web-service-tutorial-from-contract-to-security/#comment-302

I imported the project prerson in eclipse, added the jar files, but when I run the project and typed :

```
http://localhost:8080/person/Person.wsdl
```

I got this error :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet spring-ws threw exception
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
root cause
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name ‘Person’ defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xml/serializer/TreeWalker
```

Can you please help me ?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xml/serializer/TreeWalker
```

Add [`xalan-2.7.1.jar`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/xalan/xalan/2.7.1/xalan-2.7.1.jar) to your CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 1):

Use `xalan-2.7.0.jar`. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem, just added serializer.jar to my classpath and it's working now, it looks like xalan-2.7.1.jar is missing TreeWalker.